# Dismiss message notification if comment already has been seen

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

It would be nice if the system dismissed message notifications for comments that have already been seen. Often I will monitor a question and answer thread for new comments to my questions or responses. It is annoying to have to go up and clear the red box when I have already seen the response to my comment.

Comment: But what if you loaded the page to look at another answer, or the question, and didn't notice the comment that caused the notification?

Comment: I get what you're saying but on questions with many answers I may look at the page but not at the *part of the page* where the reply to me is

Comment: @Servy: I suppose it would apply if you are on the page and click the notification that there is a new comment and it loads the new comment without doing a page refresh.